# $em->persist($countries); не выполняется

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

При выводе кода срабатывает ошибка:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "persist" of class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry".

Рылся не смог найти решения. Вот мой код:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $client = new Client();

    // Go to the booking.com website
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.booking.com/country.en-gb.html');
    $crawler = $crawler->filter('body#b2countryPage > div#bodyconstraint > div#bodyconstraint-inner > div.lp_flexible_layout_content_wrapper > div#countryTmpl > div.block_third > div.block_header');

    foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
        $countries = new Countries();

        $countries->setCountry($domElement->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent);
        $countries->setHotels($domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent);

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
        $em->persist($countries);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Своим сообщением об ошибке, PHP недвусмысленно дает вам понять, что у объекта класса `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry` нет метода `persist`. И он, что характерно, прав.

А решение тривиально, нужно из сервиса `doctrine` получать экземпляр `EntityManager`:

```
// Обратите внимание на "getManager".
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em->persist($countries);
$em->flush();
```

А вот и ссылка на [официальное руководство](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) по нужной теме.

Comment: Спасибо я сделал немного подругому: $countries->setCountry($domElement->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent);
            $countries->setHotels($domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent);

            $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

            $em = $doctrine->getManager();

            $em->persist($countries);

            $em->flush();

Comment: @MaximYakubenko, тоже неплохо. Главное, что вы поняли, что `EntityManager` еще нужно извлечь из сервиса doctrine :)